# Active tab nav in mdc-tab-bar using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, material-design

I have a nav tab class with two tabs with material and I want to show the second tab.

I have tried with jQuery but that is not working for me.

Here my HTML :

```html
<div class="mdc-tab-bar" role="tablist">
   <div class="mdc-tab-scroller">
      <div class="mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-area">
         <div class="mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-content nav nav-tabs" id="exTabs">
            <button class="nav-item nav-link mdc-tab mdc-tab--active" id="nav_tns_tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav_tns" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0" style="border:0px">
            <span class="mdc-tab__content">
            <span class="mdc-tab__text-label text-uppercase tab-mdc-title details-text-style" style="font-size: 14px">TNS</span>
            </span>
            <span class="mdc-tab-indicator mdc-tab-indicator--active">
            <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
            </span>
            <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="nav-item nav-link mdc-tab" id="nav_act_tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav_act" role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0" style="border:0px">
            <span class="mdc-tab__content">
            <span class="mdc-tab__text-label text-uppercase tab-mdc-title details-text-style" style="font-size: 14px">Activite</span>
            </span>
            <span class="mdc-tab-indicator">
            <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
            </span>
            <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
            </button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


<div class="tab-content mt-4" style="display: block;position: relative;width: 100%;margin-bottom: 56px;">
   <div class="tab-pane active mt-3" id="nav_tns">
      <div class="mdc-card demo-card">
      </div>
      <div class="mdc-card demo-card mt-3">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade mt-3" style="" id="nav_act">
      <div class="mdc-card demo-card">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here my code Jquery :

```js
activaTab('nav_act');


function activaTab(tab) {
$('.nav-tabs [href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
};
```

So how can I solve this problem with jquery or by adding specific class like show active in bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add the proper libraries. As you can see in this example, the default tab is the second.

```js
activaTab('nav_act');

function activaTab(tab) {
  $('.nav-tabs [href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
};
```

```css
.show {
  background-color: red!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/4.0.2/bootstrap-material-design.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<div class="mdc-tab-bar" role="tablist">
  <div class="mdc-tab-scroller">
    <div class="mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-area">
      <div class="mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-content nav nav-tabs" id="exTabs">
        <button class="nav-item nav-link mdc-tab mdc-tab--active" id="nav_tns_tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav_tns" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0" style="border:0px">
            <span class="mdc-tab__content">
            <span class="mdc-tab__text-label text-uppercase tab-mdc-title details-text-style" style="font-size: 14px">TNS</span>
            </span>
            <span class="mdc-tab-indicator mdc-tab-indicator--active">
            <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
            </span>
            <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="nav-item nav-link mdc-tab" id="nav_act_tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav_act" role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0" style="border:0px">
            <span class="mdc-tab__content">
            <span class="mdc-tab__text-label text-uppercase tab-mdc-title details-text-style" style="font-size: 14px">Activite</span>
            </span>
            <span class="mdc-tab-indicator">
            <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
            </span>
            <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
         </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="tab-content mt-4" style="display: block;position: relative;width: 100%;margin-bottom: 56px;">
  <div class="tab-pane active mt-3" id="nav_tns">
    <div class="mdc-card demo-card">
    </div>
    <div class="mdc-card demo-card mt-3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-3" style="" id="nav_act">
    <div class="mdc-card demo-card">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is dosn't work for me also when i try to run your code snippet the first tab is default selected

Comment: @mecabpazzo95 when you run the snippet the default is the second, I put a red color for you to notice it. As for why this isn't working for you I can't help more without any more detail... "this doesn't work for me" is not enough information :)

Comment: @mecabpazzo95 yes :)

Comment: I mean, if the goal was to just get jquery to target a thing, then this got there.